# Testcontainers start two containers instead of one in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, flyway, testcontainers

I'm using Testcontainers 1.15.3 with Spring Boot 2.4 and Junit5.
When I run my test, testcontainers starts the first container and execute flyway scripts and then stop the first container. Immediatly a second container is started (without launching flyway scripts).
My test fail because the second container does not contain data.

Abstract class:

```
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
//...
}
```

Test class:

```
class ClassTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest{
    
    @Test
    void getById () throws Exception {
    //...
    }

}
```

Property file for test (jdbc url contains jdbc:**tc** to launch testcontainer):

```
spring.flyway.locations = classpath:database/structure,classpath:database/data
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.3:///databasename?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:src/test/resources/database/dataset/add_user.sql
```

Logs after launching test :

```
...
...
2021-06-21 12:56:52 [main] INFO   [postgres:13.3] - Creating container for image: postgres:13.3
2021-06-21 12:56:52 [main] INFO   [postgres:13.3] - Starting container with ID: 6a41054e8ec0f9045f8db9e945134234458a0e60b6157618f6f139cdf77d0cc4
2021-06-21 12:56:52 [main] INFO   [postgres:13.3] - Container postgres:13.3 is starting: 6a41054e8ec0f9045f8db9e945134234458a0e60b6157618f6f139cdf77d0cc4
...
...
2021-06-21 12:56:53 [main] INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema "public" to version "1.1.001 - init structure"
...
...
2021-06-21 12:56:55 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-06-21 12:56:55 [main] INFO   [postgres:13.3] - Creating container for image: postgres:13.3
2021-06-21 12:56:55 [main] INFO   [postgres:13.3] - Starting container with ID: f02fccb0706f047918d849f897ce52bf41870a53821663b21212760c779db05f
2021-06-21 12:56:55 [main] INFO   [postgres:13.3] - Container postgres:13.3 is starting: f02fccb0706f047918d849f897ce52bf41870a53821663b21212760c779db05f
```

As we see in the logs above, two containers are created.

Could you help me to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something but I can’t spot the place in your code where testcontainers lib is used in the first place. Can you clarify?

Comment: testcontainers is automatically used because in the property file above the jdbc url starts with **jdbc:tc** (tc for testcontainers)

Comment: I suspect a spring initialization problem which causes this loading to be done twice, or maybe a problem with tescontainers

Comment: I have the same issue with Spring Boot 2.5.3 and liquibase, TestContainer 1.16, Junit 5 with multiple datasources

Comment: @François-DavidLessard see response below, I hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my case: remove flyway user and password properties to use only spring ones. The duplication of these properties caused the double launch of the datasourse.

**Before**

```
spring:
  flyway:
    locations: [ classpath:flyway-scripts ]
    user: xxx
    password: xxx
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
```

**After**

```
spring:
  flyway:
    locations: [ classpath:flyway-scripts ]
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I fixed it is by adding `?TC_DAEMON=true` to the datasource url.
(in my case I used `postgis`, so just replace it with `jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.3`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgis:9.6-2.5:///dbname?TC_DAEMON=true
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: 'classpath:db/migration'
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}
    user: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
    validate-on-migrate: true
```

Comment: Adding `TC_DAEMON=true` to the database url fixed the issue for me. I was already using `jdbc:tc:postgresql:13`. Thank you.